Building robot tutorial not working for MacOS
This is my first look at Gazebo.
I am using a Mac - and the installation went through fine.
I then started to do this tut: https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/building_robot
The first command to try in the tut is:
gz sim ./building_robot.sdf

Which produces this error:
On macOS `gz sim` currently only works with either the -s argument
or the -g argument, you cannot run both server and gui in one terminal.
See https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/44 for more info.

So, I changed it to:
gz sim -g ./building_robot.sdf

However, this command does not open any window, and it does not terminate with an error.
This is related to Issue 44 and I probably need more than one command to run this SDF file.
Which commands must I run to get this first example to work?

Use two terminal sessions to run.
In the first, start the server:
gz sim -s ./building_robot.sdf
In the second, start the user interface:
gz sim -g ./building_robot.sdf
